# .htaccess ErrorDocument is not acting as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to set the redirect for a 404 inside my .htaccess file but it doesn't seem to be working. If I try a relative URL starting with a / that isn't found. If I try a full URL from https:... that doesn't work either.

Currently the first line of the htaccess file is

```
ErrorDocument 404 "test to see"
```

This also isn't working.

I know the htaccess file is working as it is used for other things.

Any ideas on what the problem might be and how to solve it please?

```
ErrorDocument 404 "test to see"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
```

Comment: added in edit above

Comment: Try: `ErrorDocument 404 /` and enter a 404 URL to test

Comment: tried ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404 which doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.. had a duplicate htaccess file in another subdirectory, causing a conflict. Sorry for the inconvenience of those trying to help but posting this so hopefully someone sees this to help them..

Answer (score 0):

You should check in apache configuration files if ErrorDocument is allowed in .htaccess.
Use `AllowOverride FileInfo` to allow ErrorDocument.

Comment: set this as first line and still not working, is there anything I need to do to make it work with this?

Comment: Did you put `AllowOverride FileInfo` into httpd.conf file?

Comment: no, i dont have that file in my system? maybe hidden from me

Comment: What operating system do you use? For example it's location can be `/usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf` in FreeBSD. P.S. Don't forget to restart apache after editing it's configuration.